# Function showing output to textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Good Day,
I'm using visualstudio2019, and I have function like this:

```
Sub doQR()
    Dim SallerName As String = gethexstring(1, "Bobs Records")
    Dim VATReg As String = gethexstring(2, "310122393500003")
    Dim DateTimeStr As String = gethexstring(3, "2022-04-25T15:30:00Z")
    Dim TotalAmt As String = gethexstring(4, "10000.00")
    Dim VatAmt As String = gethexstring(5, "150.00")
    Dim decString As String = SallerName & VATReg & DateTimeStr & TotalAmt & VatAmt
    Console.WriteLine(decString)
    Console.WriteLine(HexToBase64(decString))
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

I want to show the output in a textbox (output.text)

Thanks,

Comment: `Me.textBox1.Text = "Hello, World"`

Comment: @Dai Me not necessary in VS 2019.

Comment: @Mary Not just 2019, the `Me` and `this` keywords have always been optional in VB.NET and C# going back to 2001, however they serve a very useful purpose: to allow readers to differentiate between instance and static members; and I don't know why people are so dismissive of them (_human factors_ are important). To that end, I've set-up my team's `.editorconfig`  to always require `this.` for instance member access or raise a compiler warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub doQR()
     Dim SallerName As String = gethexstring(1, "Bobs Records")
     Dim VATReg As String = gethexstring(2, "310122393500003")
     Dim DateTimeStr As String = gethexstring(3, "2022-04-25T15:30:00Z")
     Dim TotalAmt As String = gethexstring(4, "10000.00")
     Dim VatAmt As String = gethexstring(5, "150.00")
     Dim decString As String = SallerName & VATReg & DateTimeStr & TotalAmt & VatAmt
     Console.WriteLine(decString)
     Console.WriteLine(HexToBase64(decString))
     Console.Read()

     output.text = HexToBase64(decString)
End Sub
```

Or if you want to just show `decString`, then replace this line:

```
output.text = HexToBase64(decString)
```

With:

```
output.text = decString
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a TextBox

```vb
Sub doQR()
    Dim SallerName As String = gethexstring(1, "Bobs Records")
    Dim VATReg As String = gethexstring(2, "310122393500003")
    Dim DateTimeStr As String = gethexstring(3, "2022-04-25T15:30:00Z")
    Dim TotalAmt As String = gethexstring(4, "10000.00")
    Dim VatAmt As String = gethexstring(5, "150.00")
    Dim decString As String = SallerName & VATReg & DateTimeStr & TotalAmt & VatAmt
    Console.WriteLine(decString)
    Console.WriteLine(HexToBase64(decString))
    Console.Read()
    ' do this
    TextBox1.Text = decString
End Sub
```